# How to enforce scala macro annotation constraints on annotated classes?

Tags: scala, macros, annotations

I am trying to implement a "simple" util library that puts annotated scalatest suite in a Suites instance to give them a certain running context.

```
trait MyContext extends BeforeAndAfterAll {
  //declarations of values
  override def beforeAll() = {/* run various init procedures */}
  override def afterAll() = {/* tear everything down */}
}
```

That part works and I can use it if I code the Suites instance myself.
What I would like to code is scala annotations with a macro that will take all annotated org.scalatest.Suite subtypes and generate the Suites class as in:

```
class testThisInContext extends StaticAnnotation{ /* ...  */}

@testThisInContext
class TestOne extends WordSpec {}

@testThisInContext
class TestTwo extends FlatSuite {}
```

And would then generated:

```
class InContextSuites extends Suites(new TestOne, new TestTwo) with MyContext {}
```

and also modify the classes by adding the `@org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover` annotation to them (to avoid execution out of context).

I need a way to interrupt the application of the macro (and throw an error) when the annotated class is not a subclass of Suite (which would make the generated class not compile).

I also have not figured out how to type check annotations in the modifiers instance of a ClassDef (in order to add an annotation if needed).

Comment: As I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292754/what-are-the-annotees-of-a-scala-macro-annotation-or-how-many-times-is-macro-ap, this is something that'll be very hard as is in the current framework. There might be workarounds, though. E.g. would it be possible for you to replace the definition of the existing class with its transformed version?

Comment: There is the requirement of adding a new (java) annotation to prevent double execution of scalatests. So I have no problem transforming the defined class.